# Slow wlan0 compared to eth0?

Tags: performance, wireless-networking, ipv6, linux-mint

#### Note:

DNS:

- using [OpenDNS](http://www.opendns.com/)

Wireless NIC:

```
Intel Corporation PRO/Wireless 3945ABG
```

Kernel module:

```
iwl3945
```

`uname -r`

```
2.6.28-11-generic
```

Release:

```
Distributor ID: LinuxMint
Description:    Linux Mint 7 Gloria - Main Edition
Release:    7
Codename:   Gloria
```

ip a | grep inet6:

```
inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
inet6 fe80::21b:38ff:fe0c:d718/64 scope link
```

tail /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf

```
# blacklist ipv6
blacklist ipv6
```

#### Question

- How to improve the connection speed, to match with (or similar) to Ethernet or Win NT 5.1 wireless driver?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your wireless card is 802.11a/b/g, which has a [max physical layer throughput of 54 Mbit/sec](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/802.11#802.11g). This maximum is rarely achieved in 'normal operating conditions' for most people, and you're more likely to see much slower speeds. Compared to a typical 100 Mbit ethernet card which has a max physical layer throughput of ... 100 Mbit, you should not expect to reach the same level of performance.

What you gain in mobility and convenience with Wireless is supposed to outweigh the speed/performance benefits of being tied down with ethernet. Bondage puns unintended, but [channel bonding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Channel_bonding) puns implied.

Fwiw, IPv6 is not *primarily* intended to provide performance gains, it's main benefit is increased [address availability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ipv6#Larger_address_space). Disabling it may or may not affect performance.

There's a myriad of reasons for differences in Windows vs Linux drivers, not least of which is whether the vendor contributed the driver to Linux. You may be able to tune kernel network parameters with `sysctl`, or by manipulating the driver module load options. Finally, the driver from Windows may load on Linux using NDISwrapper.

For more information on sysctl:

- On Ubuntu and Debian systems the file `/usr/share/doc/procps/examples/sysctl.conf` is heavily commented.
- The man pages for `sysctl` and `sysctl.conf` may be helpful.
- Some performance [settings on Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/performance-tuning-with-system-control-sysctl-in-ubuntu.html) with sysctl.

There seems to be more information about sysctl on Linux 2.4 kernels than 2.6. I'd have to go delving into the Linux source code documentation for more.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I understand this. However, on Win NT 5.1, the throughput is much greater compared to Linux (as per above). I suspect disabling IPv6 to improve performance?

Comment: Do you know where I can find sysctl "network parameters" references (to that of sysctl -a?

Answer (score 3):

If your Access Point has another device on it that can only do B speeds, then it's possible that it's stepping down all of its clients, including your g card.

Might want to enforce g on the AP if that's an option.

Comment: I don't understand. What is an "AP"?

Comment: @Aaron: AP = access point. Yours may be integrated as part of a wireless router.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend doing a site survey of the electromagnetic spectrum.  If someone is using the same frequencies that would explain the performance issues you are having. I discussed an issue similar to this in another thread.  [Here is the answer I gave to a similar question.](https://superuser.com/questions/14113/best-way-to-determine-source-of-home-network-slow-downs/14152#14152)